# Set length of field padding and decimal precision at the same time

Tags: java, format

Is it possible to set length of field padding in the same line as setting the decimal precision? I want `firstPlaceTime` to display with 3 decimal points, like 8.250 instead of 8.25. Perhaps something like `%8s%3f` or `%8s.3f`?

```
System.out.format("%-10s%1s%-18s%1s%8s%1s%16s%-10s","Level " + level,  "| ", firstPlaceName, "| ", firstPlaceTime + "s ", "|", timeGain + "s ahead |", " " + numberOfRunners + " runners");
```

Comment: Is `firstPlaceTime` already a String? In that case, you'd need to format it before passing it to the `.format`. If it is a `double` (or `float`), then you could use `%8.3f`. Aside: Why are you mixing the format with String concatenation? Just put the dividers and text in the format itself.

Comment: @KevinO `firstPlaceTime` is a double. I tried using `%8.3f` and it throws the error IllegalFormatConversion. And I'm not familiar with adding dividers and text to the format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows an approach to building the format String as well as using the `%8.3f` to display a double.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String level = "Beginning";
    String firstPlaceName = "TheWinner!";
    double firstPlaceTime = 180.234534D;
    double timeGain = 10.2D;
    int numberOfRunners = 10;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Level %-10s"); //the level
    sb.append("|"); //divider
    sb.append("%-18s"); //name of winner
    sb.append("|"); //divider
    sb.append("%8.3f s "); //winning time
    sb.append("|"); //divider
    sb.append("%8.3f s ahead"); //time gain
    sb.append("|"); //divider
    sb.append("%5d runners"); // # of runners

    System.out.format(sb.toString(),
            level,
            firstPlaceName,
            firstPlaceTime,
            timeGain,
            numberOfRunners);

}
```

Output:

```
Level Beginning |TheWinner!        | 180.235 s |  10.200 s ahead|   10 runners
```

**Edit**: to elaborate on a question in the comment. The OP indicated an attempt to use `%8.3f` and received a format error. `firstPlaceTime` is a double. However, the parameter was specified as:

```
...,firstPlaceTime + "s ",...
```

When the `+ "s "` was provided as a parameter, it would have been converted to a `String`, and then passed to the `.format()`. As a `String`, it would not be a `double` to format via the `%8.3f` specification. It is part of the reason for suggesting moving the text into the format specification rather than attempting
the various String concatenations in the parameters.

Comment: This appears to be a much better format, thanks for showing it to me. Just curious but why doesn't `8.3f` work in my original version of the code?

Comment: @JoshCorreia, please see the elaboration in the answer. But basically by specifying `firstPlaceTime + "s "`, the parameter became a `String`, and was no longer a double.